# How to have 2 Ajax Calls for 2 different PHP files?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having 3 `php` files,
first one is `posts.php` ,inside this file some `PHP` code and here's the `javascript` and `AJAX` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("table").on('click','a',function() {

        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: 'posts_info.php',
        data: {id:ID},
        success: function(html){

            $("#more"+ID).before(html);
            alert('this is the info');
            }
        });

    });

$('#content').on('click','.more',function( event){

    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    if(ID)
    {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'posts_load.php',
        data: {id:ID},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#loader").hide();
            $("#more"+ID).before(html);
            $("#more"+ID).remove();
            alert('this is moreee posts');

            }
        });

    }

    }); 

});

</script>
```

The first `ajax` call happends when the user clicks on an image.The second when the user clicks on a hyperlink "more". Each of the `posts.info` file and `posts_load` file loads different content
When the user clicks on the image the content from the `posts_info` is displayed successfully.Also, when the user then clicks on the more link the content of the `posts_load` is displayed successfully.The problem is when the user clicks on more ,`posts_load.php` is loaded.However after that when the user clicks on the image , nothing is displayed from "`posts_info.php`". The call is made successfully till the alert part however nothing is displayed.Any help?

Comment: Can you put some html example to view what returns every fuction? PHP Server lines would be perfect too

Comment: You probably need another ajax-call in your ajax success function to work

Comment: try if removing `$("#more"+ID).remove();` will fix this.. maybe you could `hide()` it instead?

Comment: No problem. I was just too lazy to write a decent answer. Please accept the answer below, Manwal was nice enough to write it in properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> problem is when the user clicks on more ,posts_load.php is
>   loaded.However after that when the user clicks on the image , nothing
>   is displayed from "posts_info.php".The call is made successfully till
>   the alert part however nothing is displayed

As i can see your code may be problem is this:

When you click on Image, In second ajax call you are removing element:

```
$("#more"+ID).remove();
```

Then you are adding when click on `a`

```
$("#more"+ID).before(html);
```

Its not adding response content because element is already removed from [**DOM**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).